# Using names instead numbers for index of an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I can't recall how to do below example. I forgot X(

so if a collection SEASON has four elements, { spring, summer, fall, winter }

You could directly access to these elements by...

SEASON.spring or,
SEASON.summer... and so on.

also you could do below example at the same time

SEASON[1]
SEASON[2] and so on...

SEASON is not a class. It is some kind of variable.

I will thank you for any guide you provide :D

Comment: why not do that as an enum and access it by it's name..?

Comment: What you're looking for is an enum.

Comment: Probably an enum. But you can try it with structs too.

Comment: ENUM! right! Thank you. However, what do you mean I can do it with structs? would u be kind to explain a bit further? I do seem to understand what you mean, but an example could help me to rich my understanding. Thank you!

Comment: @DJKRAZE I found a flaw in my logic. I realized that what I need is not "enum". What I planned to do was to make a library that contains another type of library that contains many images. The library that contains many images have three different images. The three different images should have a name tag on them. So one of them should be STAND one of them should be SIT and one of them should be DEAD.

Comment: I could make an array of an image but that's not how I wana do it. I wana use enum like style

Comment: Personally I would make an enum then user1143720 it's also easier in my opinion when assiging things to use an enum like var someVar=SomeEnum.SIT; or someVar = SomeEnum.STAND, ect... it also boils down to readability too and extensibility here is a good article to look at as well in your spare time.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34753/Symbols-as-extensible-enums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are always in the same position, you could do :

```
enum Seasons {Spring, Summer, Fall, Winter};
```

Example of accessing one of the seasons by :

```
SeasonsArray[(int)Seasons.Spring]
```

Comment: that wont work if you did something line var season = Seasons.Spring; it would return Spring Where has SeasonsArray been defined. try it out you should probably get a compiler error

Comment: You would have to use: `SeasonsArray[(int)Seasons.Spring]`.  You need to do an explicit cast in this instance.

Comment: @Mike Cowan Good catch, editing answer.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Oh, I ended up using enum. After some study I realized I could use enum. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome choice.. I was just lending an additional way of getting the same results.. I personlly prefer enum myself..

Answer (score 2):

You could either use an `enum` as array index (so it'll be still a number, and you explicitly specify enum values from 0 to 3), or use a `Dictionary` instead of an `array`.

You would then access your data using a key:

```
Dictionary<string, YourCurrentArrayType> dic = new Dictionary<string, YourCurrentArrayType>();
dic.Add("Summer", ...);
dic.Add("Spring", ...);
...
var obj = dic["Summer"];
var obj2 = dic["Spring"];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want this capability and want to avoid casts, you can write your own class for it.  I wanted to be able to easily index an array using an `enum` in a project I'm working on so I wrote a simple class to do it:

```
public class ArrayEnumIndex<TEnum, TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement> 
    where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    public int Length { get; }
    public TElement this[TEnum index] { get; set; }
    public void Clear();
    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index);
    public bool Exists(Predicate<TElement> match);
    public TEnum? FindIndex(Predicate<TElement> match);
    public IEnumerable<TEnum> FindAllIndices(Predicate<TElement> match);
    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator();
}
```

You can do this with a normal array, but I find it cleaner this way.  So with the Seasons `enum` you could use this in this manner:

```
ArrayEnumIndex<Seasons, int> seasons = new ArrayEnumIndex<Seasons, int>();
seasons[Seasons.Winter] = 0;
```

There are some drawbacks.  You can't constrain a generic type parameter to be an `enum` (without some trickery), so this class does some run time checking.  It works for enumerations that have an underlying type of `int` with zero-based sequential values.